# Get back cards in google now

Tags: google-now, maps, google

I turned off navigation suggestions in google now by mistake. I hit never show this card again. I was driving, honest mistake :P Now is there any way to get them back? I have tried anything I can think of. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Magic wand at the bottom of Google Now should do it (that is if you turned them off). If you just flicked the tile away they will be back so don't worry. If not just go into the magic wand menu and set the way you "get around" to another mode of transportation, then change it back to driving.